# How to deal with tags when importing a json file to MySQL using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I can't seem to find any references or examples (or I'm not looking in the right spot) for information regarding dealing with tags. More specifically, importing the tags into MySQL using PHP/PDO. I can import all the single valued fields but cannot find how to deal with tags since the number of tags for each record varies. What is the best way to handle this?

Ive setup my database like so...

[image]

Example JSON data...

```
{
    "name": "Google", 
    "uri": "https://www.google.com", 
    "description": "The largest and most popular search engine in the world",
    "tags": ["search", "web apps", "adwords"],
}, 
{
    "name": "NFL", 
    "uri": "https://www.nfl.com", 
    "description": "The National Football League",
    "tags": ["sports", "football"],
}, 
{
    "name": "CNN", 
    "uri": "https://www.cnn.com", 
    "description": "Cable News Network",
    "tags": [],
},
```

Here is the PHP/PDO code I am using to import the single valued fields...

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite/?format=json');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into bookmark values(?,?,?)");

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['uri']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $row['description']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Importing tags? Do you intend to create a tagging system?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, creating a tags table, then a map between bookmarks and tags.

What I would do, is explode or json_decode the tags value from the json string.
Iterate through the array and check if the current tag is in the tags table, if so, add the relationship to the map, if not, insert the tag, then insert the relationship into the map.

(Doing it that way ensures you only ever have one copy of a tag in the tags table.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    //insert new bookmark
    $sth_bkmk = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO bookmark(name, uri, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $sth_bkmk->execute(array($row['name'], $row['uri'], $row['desc..']));
    save_tags($db->lastInsertId(), $row['tags']);
}

function save_tags($bkmk_id, $tags) {
    if (!$bkmk_id || !$tags) return;
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        //check if tag already exists
        $sth_tag = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM tag WHERE name=?');
        $sth_tag->execute(array($tag));
        $tag_id = $sth_tag->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!$tag_id) {
            $sth_tag = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tag(name) VALUES(?)');
            $sth_tag->execute(array($tag));
            $tag_id['id'] = $db->lastInsertId();
        }
        //insert new tagmap
        $sth_tagmap = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tagmap(bookmark_id, tag_id) VALUES(?, ?)');
        $sth_tagmap->execute(array($bkmk_id, $tag_id['id']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK to **insert** tags into MySql you would do something on the following lines:

`insert_tags($tags);`

`$tags` would naturally be an array and would require a loop.

The SQL for `insert_tags($tags)` would look similar to this:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO`tags`(tag) VALUES (:tag);`

The `IGNORE` keyword is so that you don't insert duplicates. Say, someone uses 'candy' as a tag many times.

After the above move on to a function like this : `tag_*()` the asterisk (*) is a name you can supply that makes sense to your application. Such as `tag_photo()`, `tag_article()` etc.

Let's use `tag_photo()` as an example, assuming you have a table for `photos`. This function should take the primary id of the photo and the tags that were used to tag the photo. Like this `tag_photo($photo_id, array $tags)`.

**Note: `insert_tags()` must be called before this function is called.**

`tag_photo()` would do something along the following lines.

1. Get the id's of all the `$tags` that were inserted with
   `insert_tags()`
2. Save this as an array `$ids`
3. Loop through `$ids` inserting values into a middle table called
   `tagged_photos` that links the two tables `photos` and `tags`, in
   your case it would be `tagmap`.

The SQL would look something like this:

`INSERT INTO`tagged_photos`(photo_id, tag_id) VALUES (:photo_id, :tag_id)`

You would loop through this SQL statement using the `$ids` array earlier.

It would make sense that `insert_tags()` and `tag_photo()` be within a function. In your case `bookmark()`. In `bookmark()` you would need the primary id before calling `insert_tags()` and `tag_*` as you will need it.